# Environment variables for application running under Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, coding-style, jvm, environment-variables

OK, this is ugly. I've got a .war file that runs in a Tomcat 6 instance on a Linux box (CentOS 5). The Java code includes a call to the `Runtime.exec(cmd)` method, where it shells out to a 1-line shell script that runs a native application. (`R`, if you're curious...) All's well, except the native app needs to have some environment variables set to that it can do stuff like access a database. I can't edit the java code and recompile. I suppose I could edit the contents of the .war file, but I don't know what to edit. But I think that's OK -- child processes usually inherit the parent's environment, right? So I just need the environment of the JVM to include the ORACLE_HOME and other environment variables, I think.

I found out that you can put variables in the `bin/setenv.sh` file which are used when the tomcat process loads. I tried adding the environment variables there, but that doesn't work.

So:

1. Is there a way to set environment variables that will be inherited down to the JVM process level, so that my exec'd application also inherits those variables?
2. If not, what should I edit in the .war file to set those variables manually? (And how ugly is that??)

Thanks for helping me get this ugly hack working!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer for #2 is easy. As I said, the exec() call calls a shell script that runs the application. I just opened up the .war file, and added some `export FOO=bar` lines to it, dropped the result back in the tomcat webapps directory, and it worked.

Ugly as heck, though. If anyone has a good answer for option #1, they'll get credit for answering this one...